# Changed light doesn’t work

Tags: electrical

I do absolutely no electrical work. But today my mom changed our light in our kitchen saying it would be easy.

We connected the green wire to the green, white to white and black to black after turning the power off. We switched the power back on and the light worked, but wouldn’t turn off.

We switched the black to the red wire in the socket, and had caps on but we forgot to put a cap on the live black wire and we turned the power on and it sparked and the light wouldn’t come on.

We tried turning the lights in the kitchen and NONE of the other lights will come on now, we live in a townhouse with the bathroom off the kitchen and a total of 5 lights won’t come on.

The power with the electrical plugs work but the lights don’t.

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: You might have tripped the breaker.  Try to reset the breaker by moving it to the off position and then to the on position...  Cap all necessary wires.

Comment: I did that, and also replaced all fuses just to be sure. We took the light completely down and capped the open fuses and the lights still don’t work.

Comment: It means you need someone with more knowledge on site to help you,  it may not be enough to have us talk you through it. **Electricity can be dangerous**.  BUT if you can post photos of the wiring in the switch box and the fixture box it may help. Plus more details about the light, is it a single switch or controlled by two switches. ?? Are other lights on the same switch?

Comment: Do you have any outlets in the area that have a red  and a black button in the middle or test and reset in the middle?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box in question please?

Comment: do you really have a circuit breaker AND fuses? that seems odd.